Looking for a way to optimize my Javascript code
I am currently using a script that copies both the data and formatting of cells. While the code functions correctly, it is not performing efficiently. Even after incorporating a condition based on the last used row in Column C, the performance issues persist.
The process takes approximately 10 minutes to copy around 3,500 rows from five folders. Although I recognize my experience with this programming language is limited.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance from experts in identifying and resolving this issue.
Thank you.
function copyDataWithColorsToMasterSheet() {
  var folderIds = ['', '', '', '', ''];
  var masterSheetId = '';
  var masterSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetId);
  var masterSheet = masterSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  masterSheet.clear(); // Clear the master sheet to avoid duplicate data

  folderIds.forEach(function(folderId) {
    processFolder(folderId, masterSheet);
  });
}

function processFolder(folderId, masterSheet) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);

  var batchData = [];
  var batchBackgrounds = [];
  
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    processSheet(file, batchData, batchBackgrounds);
  }

  if (batchData.length > 0) {
    var masterLastRow = masterSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    var targetRange = masterSheet.getRange(masterLastRow, 1, batchData.length, batchData[0].length);
    targetRange.setValues(batchData);
    targetRange.setBackgrounds(batchBackgrounds);
  }

  var subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    var subfolder = subfolders.next();
    processFolder(subfolder.getId(), masterSheet);
  }
}

function processSheet(file, batchData, batchBackgrounds) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(file);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  var lastUsedRowInColumnC = getLastUsedRowInColumnC(sheet);
  if (lastUsedRowInColumnC < 2) return;

  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastUsedRowInColumnC - 1, lastColumn);
  
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var backgrounds = dataRange.getBackgrounds();
  
  // Append data and backgrounds to batch arrays
  batchData.push.apply(batchData, data);
  batchBackgrounds.push.apply(batchBackgrounds, backgrounds);
}

function getLastUsedRowInColumnC(sheet) {
  var columnC = sheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();
  for (var i = columnC.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (columnC[i][0] !== "") {
      return i + 1; // Return the row number (1-based index)
    }
  }
  return 1; // Default to 1 if no data is found
}


The only thing I can think of is to do some of that operation in parallel - but, I'm not familiar with google-sheets scripting. I mean, does that code run on a browser or what?

yeah thinking like that, its actually JavaScript and runs on https://script.google.com/.

Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheets, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result and that was not useful, I apologize.

Although I'm not sure about your actual Spreadsheets, how about the following modification?
In this modification, I modified the following points.

Values and backgrounds are put into the destination spreadsheet after all values and backgrounds are retrieved.
In order to retrieve values and backgrounds, only one time of getValues() and getBackgrounds() is used. So, the last row index was retrieved from the values from this getValues().

When these points are reflected in the script it becomes as follows.
Modified script:
Please set your Spreadsheet ID and folder IDs to masterSheetId and folderIds, respectively.
function myFunction() {
  const masterSheetId = '###';
  const folderIds = ['###','###',,,];

  // Retrieve values and backgrounds from all Spreadsheets in the folders.
  const getValues_ = (folder, obj = { v: [], c: [] }) => {
    if (folder) {
      const files = folder.getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS);
      while (files.hasNext()) {
        const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(files.next()).getSheets()[0];
        const range = sheet.getDataRange();
        const [, ...v] = range.getValues();
        const [, ...c] = range.getBackgrounds();
        const len = v.length;
        const lastRow = len - v.slice().reverse().findIndex(r => r[2].toString());
        if (lastRow < len) {
          obj.v.push(...v.slice(0, lastRow));
          obj.c.push(...c.slice(0, lastRow));
        }
      }
      const subFolders = folder.getFolders();
      while (subFolders.hasNext()) getValues_(subFolders.next(), obj);
    }
    return obj;
  }
  const { v, c } = folderIds.reduce((o, id) => {
    const { v, c } = getValues_(DriveApp.getFolderById(id));
    if (v.length > 0) {
      o.v.push(...v);
      o.c.push(...c);
    }
    return o;
  }, { v: [], c: [] });

  // Put values and backgrounds into the destination spreadsheet.
  const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(masterSheetId).getSheets()[0].clear();
  dstSheet.getRange(1, 1, v.length, v[0].length).setValues(v).setBackgrounds(c);
}

Note:

Although, unfortunately, I do not know your actual situation, when I tested this script with 20 Spreadsheets and 20000 total rows, the processing time was about 25 seconds. I think that when the number of Spreadsheets is large, the processing time will be large.

